# Creating a table out of two tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a table based off of two tables. For example, I have a column in one table called Customer_ID and a column in another table called Debit_Card_Number. How can I make it so I can get the Customer_ID column from one table and the Debit_card_number from the other table and make a table? Thanks

Comment: What else is in the debit card table?

Comment: Use Select into <new table> using a join from the 2 existing ones. If there is no way to tell you which debit card number belongs to which customer ID then you will probably be out of luck.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: More info needed, basically you are looking for a JOIN but you need a common field to JOIN on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Two Table Names as TableOne and TableTwo and CustomerID as a common Attribute.

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS (
    SELECT 
        TableOne.Customer_ID,
        TableTwo.Debit_Card_Number
    FROM
        TableOne,
        TableTwo
    Where
    tableOne.CustomerID = tableTwo.CustomerID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a join. Use Left Join to give you the id, even if there isn't a matching card number for that id. Your value to match on will probably be the id, assuming that value is in the table with the card number

```
create table joined_table as(
    select t1.customer_id, t2.debit_card_number
    from t1
    inner join t2
    on t1.matchValue = t2.matchValue
)
```